# Kernels and Support Vector Machines - any specific motivation?

Tags: regression, logistic, svm, linear, kernel-trick

In many applications, I have seen the combination of Kernels and Support Vector Machines. Why not combine Kernels with Linear or Logistic Regression instead? Is there any explicit reason to combine Kernels and SVM?